# Flutter Camera Preview

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to both Flutter and Dart, so bear with me.
I'm trying to use Flutter to display a camera preview using the [Camera Plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera), and have two problems. 1) The preview is stretched so things look weird. 2) I want to have a `BottomNavigationBar` displayed below the preview, but the Camera Preview uses all screen space.

I initialize the camera and open the preview:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  if (!_isReady) return new Container();
  if (!controller.value.initialized) return new Container();

  return new CameraPreview(controller);
}
```

1) This is the build method for a class I've called `_CameraWidgetState`. How can I make this preview not look stretched?

2) To make the CameraWidget not use all space, I've tried putting it inside a `Scaffold` with no luck:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new CameraWidget(),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.camera), title: new Text("Left")),

      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
          title: new Text("Right"))
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Any ideas or help appreciated!

Comment: 1) if you want the camerPreview to be a fixed size, wrap it around a Container Widget

2) Container Widget - same answer

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping it in a container and further wrapping in an AspectRatio worked.

Comment: coool, i apologize i am bit too lazy to write you an answer

Comment: Thomas ... could you elaborate (i.e. show the answer)? @user1462443 says to wrap camera _around_ a Container Widget. You said you wrapped it _in_ a Container Widget.

Comment: @lilbiscuit I added my solution below. I hope this answers the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solves the problem, but there could be better solutions as well. (Thanks to @user1462442 from the comments above.)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 if (!_isReady) return new Container();
 if (!controller.value.initialized) return new Container();

 return new Scaffold(
   body: new Container(
     child: new AspectRatio(
       aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
       child: new CameraPreview(controller),
     ),
   ),
   floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
     onPressed: _isReady ? capture : null,
     child: const Icon(
       Icons.camera,
       color: Colors.white,
     ),
   ),
   floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
 );
}
```