# Recording a video with front camera in flutter the screen becames darker and narrow

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, video-recording

Recording a video with front camera in flutter the screen became darker and narrow i tried a lot but i don't have any  to resolve it

The video recording is with full screen and the face became very narrow and very darken.
I have tried with giving the resolution was also high
But the back camera is working fine

I am using camera plugin i.e.,: camera: ^0.5.2+1

But the back camera is working fine

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class CameraExampleHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraExampleHomeState createState() {
    return _CameraExampleHomeState();
  }
}

/// Returns a suitable camera icon for [direction].
IconData getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
  switch (direction) {
    case CameraLensDirection.back:
      return Icons.camera_rear;
    case CameraLensDirection.front:
      return Icons.camera_front;
    case CameraLensDirection.external:
      return Icons.camera;
  }
  throw ArgumentError('Unknown lens direction');
}

void logError(String code, String message) =>
    print('Error: $code\nError Message: $message');

class _CameraExampleHomeState extends State<CameraExampleHome>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraController controller;
  String imagePath;
  String videoPath;
  VideoPlayerController videoController;
  VoidCallback videoPlayerListener;
  bool enableAudio = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      controller?.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (controller != null) {
        onNewCameraSelected(controller.description);
      }
    }
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Camera example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: controller != null && controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                      ? Colors.redAccent
                      : Colors.grey,
                  width: 3.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          _captureControlRowWidget(),
          _toggleAudioWidget(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                _cameraTogglesRowWidget(),
                _thumbnailWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the preview from the camera (or a message if the preview is not available).
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Tap a camera',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: CameraPreview(controller),
      );
    }
  }

  /// Toggle recording audio
  Widget _toggleAudioWidget() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Enable Audio:'),
          Switch(
            value: enableAudio,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              enableAudio = value;
              if (controller != null) {
                onNewCameraSelected(controller.description);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the thumbnail of the captured image or video.
  Widget _thumbnailWidget() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            videoController == null && imagePath == null
                ? Container()
                : SizedBox(
                    child: (videoController == null)
                        ? Image.file(File(imagePath))
                        : Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio:
                                      videoController.value.size != null
                                          ? videoController.value.aspectRatio
                                          : 1.0,
                                  child: VideoPlayer(videoController)),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink)),
                          ),
                    width: 64.0,
                    height: 64.0,
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures and record videos.
  Widget _captureControlRowWidget() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: controller != null &&
                  controller.value.isInitialized &&
                  !controller.value.isRecordingVideo
              ? onTakePictureButtonPressed
              : null,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.videocam),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: controller != null &&
                  controller.value.isInitialized &&
                  !controller.value.isRecordingVideo
              ? onVideoRecordButtonPressed
              : null,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: controller != null &&
                  controller.value.isInitialized &&
                  controller.value.isRecordingVideo
              ? onStopButtonPressed
              : null,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
  Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
    final List<Widget> toggles = <Widget>[];

    if (cameras.isEmpty) {
      return const Text('No camera found');
    } else {
      for (CameraDescription cameraDescription in cameras) {
        toggles.add(
          SizedBox(
            width: 90.0,
            child: RadioListTile<CameraDescription>(
              title: Icon(getCameraLensIcon(cameraDescription.lensDirection)),
              groupValue: controller?.description,
              value: cameraDescription,
              onChanged: controller != null && controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                  ? null
                  : onNewCameraSelected,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    return Row(children: toggles);
  }

  String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  void showInSnackBar(String message) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }

  void onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(
      cameraDescription,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: enableAudio,
    );

    // If the controller is updated then update the UI.
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        showInSnackBar('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void onTakePictureButtonPressed() {
    takePicture().then((String filePath) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imagePath = filePath;
          videoController?.dispose();
          videoController = null;
        });
        if (filePath != null) showInSnackBar('Picture saved to $filePath');
      }
    });
  }

  void onVideoRecordButtonPressed() {
    startVideoRecording().then((String filePath) {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (filePath != null) showInSnackBar('Saving video to $filePath');
    });
  }

  void onStopButtonPressed() {
    stopVideoRecording().then((_) {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      showInSnackBar('Video recorded to: $videoPath');
    });
  }

  Future<String> startVideoRecording() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showInSnackBar('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }

    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Movies/flutter_test';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.mp4';

    if (controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      // A recording is already started, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      videoPath = filePath;
      await controller.startVideoRecording(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  Future<void> stopVideoRecording() async {
    if (!controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.stopVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }

    await _startVideoPlayer();
  }

  Future<void> _startVideoPlayer() async {
    final VideoPlayerController vcontroller =
        VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoPath));
    videoPlayerListener = () {
      if (videoController != null && videoController.value.size != null) {
        // Refreshing the state to update video player with the correct ratio.
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
        videoController.removeListener(videoPlayerListener);
      }
    };
    vcontroller.addListener(videoPlayerListener);
    await vcontroller.setLooping(true);
    await vcontroller.initialize();
    await videoController?.dispose();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        imagePath = null;
        videoController = vcontroller;
      });
    }
    await vcontroller.play();
  }

  Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showInSnackBar('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
    showInSnackBar('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }
}

class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraExampleHome(),
    );
  }
}

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
  }
  runApp(CameraApp());
}
```

Comment: screenshots? what package are you using to capture footage? can you share any code? There isn't enough information to help diagnose the problem

Comment: @F-1 I have edited the code please check

Comment: Great, hopefully someone can help. I can't test your code because there are references to classes and methods outside of this code shared, if you have an example that could be cut and pasted into the main file that would be even more helpful.

Comment: @F-1 I have pasted now example code please check

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved it by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your sample in Nexus 6 emulator, and here is the output:

[image]
[image]

It seems that the front and rear camera was being stretch. I've found [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15953) and you've encountered the same issue. There are other samples that you can try. Also, I've seen that the team behind the Camera Plugin [is working for a refactor](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31225) on the said plugin.

I've played with your code and implemented the solution I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61487358/8342742). Which could be some remedy atm, but there could be better solutions.

From the part:

```
   Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Tap a camera',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: CameraPreview(controller),
      );
    }
  }
```

I've applied this fix from the referenced [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61487358/8342742):

```
Widget cameraWidget(context) {
    var camera = _cameraController.value;
    // fetch screen size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
       
    // calculate scale depending on screen and camera ratios
    // this is actually size.aspectRatio / (1 / camera.aspectRatio)
    // because camera preview size is received as landscape
    // but we're calculating for portrait orientation
    var scale = size.aspectRatio * camera.aspectRatio;

    // to prevent scaling down, invert the value
    if (scale < 1) scale = 1 / scale;

    return Transform.scale(
      scale: scale,
      child: Center(
        child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
      ),
  );
}
```

Since I'm using the current version of [camera 0.8.0](https://pub.dev/packages/camera), I've considered the given solution for versions higher than 0.7.0.

Here the sample code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class CameraExampleHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraExampleHomeState createState() {
    return _CameraExampleHomeState();
  }
}

/// Returns a suitable camera icon for [direction].
IconData getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
  switch (direction) {
    case CameraLensDirection.back:
      return Icons.camera_rear;
    case CameraLensDirection.front:
      return Icons.camera_front;
    case CameraLensDirection.external:
      return Icons.camera;
  }
  throw ArgumentError('Unknown lens direction');
}

void logError(String code, String message) =>
    print('Error: $code\nError Message: $message');

class _CameraExampleHomeState extends State<CameraExampleHome>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraController controller;
  String imagePath;
  String videoPath;
  VideoPlayerController videoController;
  VoidCallback videoPlayerListener;
  bool enableAudio = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      controller?.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (controller != null) {
        onNewCameraSelected(controller.description);
      }
    }
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Camera example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: controller != null && controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                      ? Colors.redAccent
                      : Colors.grey,
                  width: 3.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          _captureControlRowWidget(),
          _toggleAudioWidget(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                _cameraTogglesRowWidget(),
                _thumbnailWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the preview from the camera (or a message if the preview is not available).
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    var camera = controller.value;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var scale = size.aspectRatio * camera.aspectRatio;
    if (scale < 1) scale = 1 / scale;
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Tap a camera',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Transform.scale(
        scale: scale,
        child: Center(
          child: CameraPreview(controller),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  /// Toggle recording audio
  Widget _toggleAudioWidget() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Enable Audio:'),
          Switch(
            value: enableAudio,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              enableAudio = value;
              if (controller != null) {
                onNewCameraSelected(controller.description);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the thumbnail of the captured image or video.
  Widget _thumbnailWidget() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            videoController == null && imagePath == null
                ? Container()
                : SizedBox(
                    child: (videoController == null)
                        ? Image.file(File(imagePath))
                        : Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio:
                                      videoController.value.size != null
                                          ? videoController.value.aspectRatio
                                          : 1.0,
                                  child: VideoPlayer(videoController)),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink)),
                          ),
                    width: 64.0,
                    height: 64.0,
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures and record videos.
  Widget _captureControlRowWidget() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: controller != null &&
                  controller.value.isInitialized &&
                  !controller.value.isRecordingVideo
              ? onTakePictureButtonPressed
              : null,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.videocam),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: controller != null &&
                  controller.value.isInitialized &&
                  !controller.value.isRecordingVideo
              ? onVideoRecordButtonPressed
              : null,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: controller != null &&
                  controller.value.isInitialized &&
                  controller.value.isRecordingVideo
              ? onStopButtonPressed
              : null,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
  Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
    final List<Widget> toggles = <Widget>[];

    if (cameras.isEmpty) {
      return const Text('No camera found');
    } else {
      for (CameraDescription cameraDescription in cameras) {
        toggles.add(
          SizedBox(
            width: 90.0,
            child: RadioListTile<CameraDescription>(
              title: Icon(getCameraLensIcon(cameraDescription.lensDirection)),
              groupValue: controller?.description,
              value: cameraDescription,
              onChanged: controller != null && controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                  ? null
                  : onNewCameraSelected,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    return Row(children: toggles);
  }

  String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  void showInSnackBar(String message) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }

  void onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(
      cameraDescription,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: enableAudio,
    );

    // If the controller is updated then update the UI.
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        showInSnackBar('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void onTakePictureButtonPressed() {
    takePicture().then((String filePath) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imagePath = filePath;
          videoController?.dispose();
          videoController = null;
        });
        if (filePath != null) showInSnackBar('Picture saved to $filePath');
      }
    });
  }

  void onVideoRecordButtonPressed() {
    startVideoRecording().then((String filePath) {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      if (filePath != null) showInSnackBar('Saving video to $filePath');
    });
  }

  void onStopButtonPressed() {
    stopVideoRecording().then((_) {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      showInSnackBar('Video recorded to: $videoPath');
    });
  }

  Future<String> startVideoRecording() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showInSnackBar('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }

    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Movies/flutter_test';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.mp4';

    if (controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      // A recording is already started, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      videoPath = filePath;
      await controller.startVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  Future<void> stopVideoRecording() async {
    if (!controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.stopVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }

    await _startVideoPlayer();
  }

  Future<void> _startVideoPlayer() async {
    final VideoPlayerController vcontroller =
        VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoPath));
    videoPlayerListener = () {
      if (videoController != null && videoController.value.size != null) {
        // Refreshing the state to update video player with the correct ratio.
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
        videoController.removeListener(videoPlayerListener);
      }
    };
    vcontroller.addListener(videoPlayerListener);
    await vcontroller.setLooping(true);
    await vcontroller.initialize();
    await videoController?.dispose();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        imagePath = null;
        videoController = vcontroller;
      });
    }
    await vcontroller.play();
  }

  Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showInSnackBar('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
    showInSnackBar('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }
}

class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraExampleHome(),
    );
  }
}

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
  }
  runApp(CameraApp());
}
```

And the actual output:

[image]
[image]

Comparing the camera preview from the before and after I've made some adjustment in your code, it seems that it could be applicable to your current scenario. You'll just need to make some adjustments considering the calculations of camera `aspectRatio`.

You can also update your post and add some sample output from your end so we can check if this solution fits.

Aside from the solution above, there are more flexible solution since many devices can vary on resolution and size. Especially if you are attempting to build for Android and iOS.

1. Choosing the aspect ratio that you want to use.
2. Finding the resolution that is closest to this ratio.
3. Displaying the preview in an [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget that is wrapped in a [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget.

However, this is probably more difficult if the camera plugin only provides the `CameraPreview` widget. You could get around this by creating your own `Texture` widget by extracting the `cameraId` from the `Controller.buildPreview()` method.

It could be something similar to the code below. However, I noticed the camera plugin still has the limitation of only providing 4/5 resolutions. So, the closest resolution to the `desiredRatio` could end up being pretty low quality.

```
class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyCameraHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyCameraHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyCameraHomeState();
  }
}

class MyCameraHomeState extends State<MyCameraHome> {
  static final double _desiredAspectRatio = 1.78;

  late final CameraController _controller;
  Widget _previewWidget = Container();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(_closestResolutionPreset());
    _controller = CameraController(cameras[0], _closestResolutionPreset());
    _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      _buildPreviewWidget();
    });
  }

  ResolutionPreset _closestResolutionPreset() {
    final Map<ResolutionPreset, double> ratios = <ResolutionPreset, double>{
      ResolutionPreset.low: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
          ? 320 / 240
          : 352 / 288,
      ResolutionPreset.medium: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
          ? 720 / 480
          : 640 / 480,
      ResolutionPreset.high: 1280 / 720,
      ResolutionPreset.veryHigh: 1920 / 1080,
    };

    double smallestDifference = 1000;
    late ResolutionPreset resultPreset;

    for (MapEntry<ResolutionPreset, double> ratio in ratios.entries) {
      final double newDifference = (ratio.value - _desiredAspectRatio).abs();
      if (newDifference < smallestDifference) {
        resultPreset = ratio.key;
        smallestDifference = newDifference;
      }
    }

    return resultPreset;
  }

  void _buildPreviewWidget() {
    Widget previewWidget = _controller.buildPreview();
    setState(() => _previewWidget = previewWidget);
  }

  Widget _buildPictureButton() {
    return InkResponse(
      onTap: () {
        //_takePicture();
        //_recordAVideo();
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 65,
        height: 65,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2)),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.camera,
          color: Colors.grey,
          size: 60,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
              child: _previewWidget,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 30,
              left: 10,
              right: 10,
              top: 15,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.switch_camera,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 32,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {} //_toggleLensDirection,
                      ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: _buildPictureButton(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];

Future<void> main() async {
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
  }
  runApp(CameraApp());
}
```