# Flutter Live Camera Overlay with other image

Tags: flutter, camera

I am new to flutter and trying to create a camera app. App needs to overlay image on top of Live Camera. Exactly as shown in image https://stackoverflow.com/a/62199339/12747470 . It will be great if someone can suggest some reference code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
     AspectRatio(
       aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
       child: CameraPreview(controller),
     ),
     Image.asset(''),
  ]
)
```

Comment: thank you very much I have a question how to make a program like this in the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0zVopYLrtQ

Answer (score 1):

I required a similar layout when working on the camera.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
     CameraPreview(),
     Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child : Container( 
           height: 120,
           child: Opacity(
              opacity:0.60,
              color: Colors.black,
           ),
        ),
     ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: thank you very much I have a question how to make a program like this in the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0zVopYLrtQ